# JAXB Binding With Java Inherited Bean Object

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

i am attempting to bind XML data to below java model bean class using JAXB Api. But i am unable to bind it. Can anyone please give suggestion or coding Using JAXB.
 i have provided my bean class and input xml.

Message.java

```
@XmlRootElement(name="Message")
class Message{

private Header header = null;
private Body body = null;

@XmlElement(name="Header")
public Header getHeader() {
    return header;
}
public void setHeader(Header header) {
    this.header = header;
}
@XmlElement(name="Body")
public Body getBody() {
    return body;
}
public void setBody(Body body) {
    this.body = body;
}
}
```

Header.Java

```
@XmlSeeAlso({ReqHeader.class})
class Header{

}
```

ReqHeader.java

```
@XmlRootElement(name="Header")
class ReqHeader extends Header{

private String msgID = null;
private String msgDesc = null;
public String getMsgID() {
    return msgID;
}
public void setMsgID(String msgID) {
    this.msgID = msgID;
}
public String getMsgDesc() {
    return msgDesc;
}
public void setMsgDesc(String msgDesc) {
    this.msgDesc = msgDesc;
}
}
```

Body.java

```
class Body{

}
```

RequestBody.java

```
class RequestBody extends Body{
private CustInfo custInfo = null;
public CustInfo getCustrInfo() {
    return custInfo;
}
public void setCustrInfo(CustInfo custInfo) {
    this.custInfo = custInfo;
}
}
```

CustInfo.java

```
class CustInfo{
private String custID = null;
public String getCustID() {
    return custID;
}
public void setCustID(String custID) {
    this.custID = custID;
}
}
```

MessageUnmarshall .java

```
public class MessageUnmarshall {

public static void main(String a[]) throws JAXBException{
    String str = "<Message> <Header> <MsgID>123</MsgID> <MsgDesc>cust     products</MsgDesc> </Header> <Body> <CustInfo> <CustID>111</CustID> </CustInfo> </Body> </Message>";
    JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(Message.class);
    Unmarshaller un = context.createUnmarshaller();
    Message msg = (Message) un.unmarshal(new StringReader(str));
}

}
```

Comment: "But I am unable to bind it" - what does that mean? Do you get an error message? What is the exact error message?

Comment: Header is not binding with ReqHeader. i mean i cannot cast..
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: com.conversion.Header cannot be cast to com.conversion.ReqHeader

Comment: @Jesper i dont know how to approach on this. Please help to resolve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Alternate way is to not use inheritance and use only header and body class and remove ReqHeader and RequestBody class.

Make the header class like this:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "Header")
class Header {
private String msgID = null;
private String msgDesc = null;

public String getMsgID() {
    return msgID;
}

public void setMsgID(String msgID) {
    this.msgID = msgID;
}

public String getMsgDesc() {
    return msgDesc;
}

public void setMsgDesc(String msgDesc) {
    this.msgDesc = msgDesc;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "ReqHeader [msgID=" + msgID + ", msgDesc=" + msgDesc + "]";
}
```

}`

and change the body class accordingly...

Comment: Thanks Embyy. But as per my requirement design Header is base class for ReqHeader. and Body is base class for RequestBody.. here ReqHeader & RequestBody is for specific services. content will vary for every services. soi must follow my design.

Comment: Can you please give me a suggestion as per my design.

Answer (score -1):

The purpose of the @XmlSeeAlso annotation is just to let your JAXB (JSR-222) implementation know that when it is processing the metadata for Resource that it should also process the metadata for the SomeItem class.

Some people mistakenly believe that it is related to mapping inheritance since that is the use case it is most often used with.

Since the subclasses of a class can not be determined using Java reflection, @XmlSeeAlso is used to let the JAXB implementation know that mappings for the subclasses should also be created.